# Не подключается по ssh ключу от других пользователей, кроме root

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, openssh

Не удается подключиться по ssh ключу.

Собственно, как делал.

- С помощью ssh-keygen сгенерировал ключ.
- С помощью ssh-copy-id скопировал ключ на сервер.
- Проверил свой id_rsa.pub и authorized_keys на сервере в .ssh папке
  пользователя. Назовем его username.  Совпадают полностью.
- Проверил authorized_keys в .ssh рута - несколько ключей. Один из них
  тот, который сгенерировал для username

Итог: от рута удается подключиться к серверу по ключу. От username - нет.
При попытке подключиться от username запрашивает пароль.

Далее проверил права на каталог username и .ssh каталог, а также содержимое. Права верные.

```
drwx------ 2 username username    6 Окт 30 12:44 .
drwxrwxr-x 5 username username   11 Окт 25 18:16 ..
-rwx------ 1 username username  406 Окт 30 12:21 authorized_keys
-rwx------ 1 username username 1675 Окт 30 12:44 id_rsa
-rwx------ 1 username username  399 Окт 30 12:44 id_rsa.pub
-rwx------ 1 username username 1195 Ноя  5 10:36 known_hosts
```

Посмотрел логи. При попытке соединиться от username возникает следующая ошибка:

> Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory
>   /home/username

Посмотрел права на каталог username - с ними тоже полный порядок

```
drwxrwxr-x  5 username username 11 Окт 25 18:16 username
```

/home/username

```
drwxrwxr-x  5 username username   11 Окт 25 18:16 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root   root      4 Ноя  5 09:36 ..
-rw-------  1 username username 4565 Ноя 15 11:55 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 username username   18 Апр 11  2018 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 username username  193 Апр 11  2018 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--  1 username username  231 Апр 11  2018 .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x  8 username username   15 Ноя  1 15:00 dehydrated
-rw-r--r--  1 username username  264 Ноя  1 15:00 dehydrated_update.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 username username   43 Окт 25 18:16 .gitconfig
drwx------  2 username username    6 Окт 30 12:44 .ssh
drwxrwxrwx 40 username username   95 Ноя 12 14:29 www
```

Уже не знаю в какую сторону смотреть.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема была все же в правах. Помогла эта статья.
http://aboutubuntu.ru/content/ssh-authentication-refused-bad-ownership-or-modes-directory

Нужно выполнить следующие команды для установки прав.

```
chmod go-w ~/
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

По шагам:

- Запрещаем запись в домашнюю директорию пользователя всем, кроме
  владельца.
- Разрешаем чтение, вход и запись в директории с настройками .ssh
  только владельцу.
- Разрешаем читать и менять файл .ssh/authorized_keys только владельцу.

Comment: ускорило ба решение проблемы - `ssh -v user@hostname`

Answer (score 0):

цитита из `$ man sshd` про файл `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`:

> If this file, the ~/.ssh directory, or the user's home directory are writable by other users, then the file could be modified or replaced by unauthorized users. In this case, sshd will not allow it to be used unless the StrictModes option has been set to “no”

выставление прав на домашний каталог и каталог `~/.ssh` (с содержимым), которые должны удовлетворить требования *sshd*, коротко и с более человекочитабельными аргументами:

```
$ chmod go-w ~
$ chmod -R go= ~/.ssh
```

---

пояснения аргументов:

1. `go-w ~` — для самого домашнего каталога пользователя (`~`) убираем (`-`) биты записи (`w`) для группы (`g`) и остальных (`o`)
2. `-R go= ~/.ssh` — рекурсивно (`-R`) убираем все права (`=пустота`) для группы (`g`) и остальных (`o`)

Answer (score 0):

Разрешения на .ssh должны быть rwxr-xr-x

```
chmod -R 755 .ssh
```

Comment: ну зачем писать несоответствующее документации? см. `$ man sshd`, про файл `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (цитирую с выделением): «If this file, **the ~/.ssh directory**, or the user's home directory are writable by other users, then the file could be modified or replaced by unauthorized users.  In this case, sshd will not allow it to be used unless the StrictModes option has been set to “no”»

Comment: А если посмотретъ в `man ssh`, то там стоит "recommended permissions are read/write/execute for the user, and not accessible by others". Но авторы мануала наверное ошибаются, как вы думаете?