# Не получается настроить подключение по ssh

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, centos7

1. Сгенерировал на своем компе ключи (у меня винда - пробовал и обычным ssh-keygen и putty)
2. Добавил на сервере в ~/.ssh/authorised_keys публичный ключ
3. Пытаюсь подключиться: `ssh root@myhost -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa` и на этом шаге меня обязательно запрашивает пароль юзера... С паролем заходит, но почему так происходит? Я хочу заходить без пароля!!! Только по файлу.

`PubkeyAuthentication yes` установлено. У меня CentOS 7 в виртуалке на этом же компе (к нему я и хочу подключаться).

Comment: на сервере: `$ chmod -R go= ~/.ssh; chmod go=~` . вообще дубликат, например, [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/906810/178576).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin что за странная команда? О_о Что это за `go`? Я не думаю что проблема в правах доступа к файлу. Я делал по инструкции и выставил папке .ssh права 700, а файлу authorised_keys 600

Comment: @alexanderbarakin зачем вы это сделали? Это не дубликат. Откройте вопрос. У меня другая проблема!!!

Comment: @alexanderbarakin я попробовал применить ваши команды - это не помогло! Пожалуйста откройте вопрос или я буду создавать дубликаты! Мне надо решить эту проблему, а в той теме решения нет!!! Это совершенно другая проблема!!!

Comment: 1. я добавил ещё дубликатов. 2. приведите в вопросе вывод `$ ls -ld ~ ~/.ssh ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. 3. если с правами всё в порядке, приведите вывод `$ ssh -vvv ...` и то, что пишет *sshd* на сервере в лог при попытке выполнения этой команды.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ахаха я понял... У меня authori**S**ed_keys было написано через `s`, а надо через `z`. Я же его вручную создавал... Банальная опечатка, спасибо. Заработало