# Не удается сменить ключи ssh на удаленном сервере

Tags: linux, сервер, centos, ssh

Сгенерировал новые ключи, скопировал в authorized_keys, перезапустил и все равно автоматом не заходит с терминала, требует пароль. Боюсь совсем отключить парольную аутентификацию, чтобы потом совсем не потерять возможность подключиться. Подскажите решение, как проверить что подключится через ключ? Сервер на centos 7. Права на ~/.ssh 700, на ~/.ssh/authorized_keys 600. Ключ id_rsa.pub копировал через ssh-copy-id, там все нормально.

Comment: ssh -v читайте для начала

Comment: А что она выводит?

Comment: Информацию о процессе подключения, вдруг там про ключи и пароли что-нибудь есть

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/919409/178576